# Delete some certain character by position in a list using python

Tags: python, python-3.5

```
import csv    
data=[['p52264'], ['p52265'], ['p52266'], ['p52267'], ['p52268'], ['p52269'], ['p52270'], ['p52271'], ['p52272'], ['p52273'], ['p52274'], ['p52275'], ['p52276'], ['p52277'], ['p52278'], ['p52279'], ['p52280'], ['p52281'], ['p52282'], ['p52283']]

print(data=[2:])
```

i want to remove only two first character from each word.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv


data=[]
ifile  = open('skills.csv', "r")
read = csv.reader(ifile)
for row in read :
    data.append(row[:1])

print(len(data))
print(data[0])

new_data=[]

for i in range(0, len(data)):
    if i%2!=0:
        new_data.append(data[i])


print(len(new_data))

with open('newskills.csv', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(0, len(new_data)):
        m_data=(new_data[i])
        writer=csv.writer(f)
        w_data=m_data[0][2:]
        writer.writerows(w_data)
```

I want to write this in csv file but it write only one charcter in one row

Comment: You are trying to remove first two elements of whole `data` list, Do it for every element `print(list(map(lambda x: x[:2], data)))`

Comment: Can you add the desired output to the question @Jay

Comment: What is new_data in code? @Jay

Comment: @SandeepKadapa I want to write the paritcular wrord in cell after removing first two character, it remove the two words properly but didn't write properly. it write only character in one cell

Comment: @JayPratapPandey check my updated solution of writing into csv. At the bottom of my solution. Do you want to remove p and 5 like you want `2264,2265...` as the list?

Comment: @SandeepKadapa It shows Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csvtotxt1.py", line 36, in <module>
    new_data = [[int(str(i).strip("['p']"))] for i in data ]
  File "csvtotxt1.py", line 36, in <listcomp>
    new_data = [[int(str(i).strip("['p']"))] for i in data ]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(lp0'

Comment: @JayPratapPandey Please update the code you are using and real data you are using. Without those it is not possible to give a solution. Because the code at bottom of my solution worked and wrote the strings in each row where as it is not working in your case. So please update.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa this is my full code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159970/discussion-between-sandeep-kadapa-and-jay-pratap-pandey).

Comment: @SandeepKadapa, I solve this issue thank you, Can you help me for extracting every type of phone number from text file using python

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the elements, and slice them:

```
data=[['p52264'], ['p52265'], ['p52266'], ['p52267'], ['p52268'], ['p52269'], ['p52270'], ['p52271'], ['p52272'], ['p52273'], ['p52274'], ['p52275'], ['p52276'], ['p52277'], ['p52278'], ['p52279'], ['p52280'], ['p52281'], ['p52282'], ['p52283']]
for d in data:
    print(d[0][1:])
```

#### outcome:

```
52264
52265
52266
52267
52268
52269
52270
52271
52272
52273
52274
52275
52276
52277
52278
52279
52280
52281
52282
52283
```

Comment: Thanks @Reblochon Masque

Answer (score 1):

list comprehension method

```
[str(i).strip("['']")[1:] for i in data]

['52264',
 '52265',
 '52266',
 '52267',
 '52268',
 '52269',
 '52270',
 '52271',
 '52272',
 '52273',
 '52274',
 '52275',
 '52276',
 '52277',
 '52278',
 '52279',
 '52280',
 '52281',
 '52282',
 '52283']
```

If you want the elements as list of lists then

```
[[str(i).strip("['p']")] for i in data ]
[['52264'],
 ['52265'],
 ['52266'],
 ['52267'],
 ['52268'],
 ['52269'],
 ['52270'],
 ['52271'],
 ['52272'],
 ['52273'],
 ['52274'],
 ['52275'],
 ['52276'],
 ['52277'],
 ['52278'],
 ['52279'],
 ['52280'],
 ['52281'],
 ['52282'],
 ['52283']]
```

If you want the int of the list then

```
[int(str(i).strip("['p']")) for i in data ]
[52264,
 52265,
 52266,
 52267,
 52268,
 52269,
 52270,
 52271,
 52272,
 52273,
 52274,
 52275,
 52276,
 52277,
 52278,
 52279,
 52280,
 52281,
 52282,
 52283]
```

Assuming `new_data` as

```
new_data = [[int(str(i).strip("['p']"))] for i in data ]
with open('newskills.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(new_data)
```

Check if this worked for you.